# Display the sale id and sale date of sales made by salesmen working from London

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have three tables:

Salesman Table

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| SID |  SNAME  | LOCATION |
+-----+---------+----------+
|   1 | Peter   | London   |
|   2 | Michael | Paris    |
|   3 | John    | Mumbai   |
|   4 | Harry   | Chicago  |
|   5 | Kevin   | London   |
|   6 | Alex    | Chicago  |
+-----+---------+----------+
```

Sale Table

```
+--------+-----+-----------+
| SALEID | SID |  SLDATE   |
+--------+-----+-----------+
|   1001 |   1 | 01-JAN-14 |
|   1002 |   5 | 02-JAN-14 |
|   1003 |   4 | 01-FEB-14 |
|   1004 |   1 | 01-MAR-14 |
|   1005 |   2 | 01-FEB-14 |
|   1006 |   1 | 01-JUN-15 |
+--------+-----+-----------+
```

Expected Result

```
+--------+-----------+
| SALEID |  SLDATE   |
+--------+-----------+
|   1001 | 01-JAN-14 |
|   1002 | 02-JAN-14 |
|   1004 | 01-MAR-14 |
|   1006 | 01-JUN-15 |
+--------+-----------+
```

I am using Oracle SQLDeveloper. I run the code below:

```
    SELECT S.SALEID, S.SLDATE
    FROM Salesman SA 
    INNER JOIN Sale S ON SA.SID = S.SID 
    WHERE SA.LOCATION = 'London';
```

but I get error:
`Error: Your result did not match the Expected result.`

If anyone can find the errors please answer.

Comment: Please include the query as *text* in the question.

Comment: `SELECT S.SALEID,S.SLDATE
FROM Salesman SA INNER JOIN Sale S ON SA.SID = S.SID WHERE SA.LOCATION = 'London';`

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Its mentioned in the image attached, error is Your Result did not matched the Expected Result.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, I got it, it was an database error, Refreshed the database and the same Query worked.
The query mentioned is correct tho.